# Cakephp - Class 'DboSource' not found

Tags: cakephp-2.0

The first block of code throw the error `Fatal error: Class 'DboSource' not found` whereas the second block of code works just fine. This beats me, both use the same line to save the created field...
Block 1

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['created'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
        $this->EbayAccount->create();
        if ($this->EbayAccount->save($this->request->data)) {
            //$this->EbayAccount->id = $this->EbayAccount->getLastInsertID();
            //$this->EbayAccount->saveField('created', DboSource::expression('NOW()'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ebay account has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ebay account could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('userId', $this->Auth->user('id'));      
}
```

Block 2

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //$this->request->data['created'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
        $this->EbayAccount->create();
        if ($this->EbayAccount->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->EbayAccount->id = $this->EbayAccount->getLastInsertID();
            $this->EbayAccount->saveField('created', DboSource::expression('NOW()'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ebay account has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ebay account could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('userId', $this->Auth->user('id'));      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for expression is :

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

$this->request->data['created'] = $db->expression('SYSDATE()');
```

if you want to use `SYSDATE()` , `NOW()`, and other expressions

it's working in cake 2.2.x

Answer (score 3):

Well, expression is not a static method, so Douglesm's solution is the better way. However, as expression does not access any attributes and PHP allows it, your code should work, too.

Make sure to have DboSource included, though:

```
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/DataSource');
```